# Right implementation of <nav> for Burger Menu (html5 semantic)

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I wonder what the right (html5 valid semantic) implementation of `<nav>` for a mobile-menu (burger menu) is.

[image: BurgerMenu]

For the desktop-view it's pretty easy. Only need to encapsulate my -List with .

But what's with the mobile view, as the -element is only a trigger for a layer which contain the real navigation items?

The Menu has following structure (simplified for better overview):

```html
<div class="rootMenu">
  <button aria-controls="menu-list-grow">
    <svg .../>
  </button>
  <div class="myCollapsableWithMenuItems">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>... MenuItems goes here</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You see, I've still added the `aria-controls` to the -element of the burger-menu.
But what is the right place to encapsulate the menu with the `<nav>`-tag?